# select html element in external jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A quick question. Is it possible to select (`html`) element in external `.js` file using `jquery`?

I have `abc.js` file and a `xyz class`. Why following code is not working?

```
//abc.js

$('.xyz').hide();
```

Comment: function should be inside `document.ready` then it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.This is possible.your code structure would be as Following:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/abc.js"></script>
```

your `abc.js`  code:

```
$(function(){ 

$('.xyz').hide();

});
```